# How I can show error message for each field in form?

Tags: forms, jsp, validation, spring-mvc

In my validator I add some description for each field, and want to display error message in form(.jsp), but when I display message for each field, the error messages is the same, what's problem, my code:

**Validator**

```
public class StoreValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Store.class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "name.empty", "Name field is empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "address", "address.empty", "Address field is empty");
}
```

}

**Controller**

```
    @Autowired
private StoreValidator storeValidator;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(storeValidator);
}

//post method create store
@RequestMapping(value = "/regStoreSuccessful", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addStorePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("storeForm") Store storeForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Principal principal, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:body");

    storeValidator.validate(storeForm,bindingResult);

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("error", bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
        //modelAndView.addObject("storeForm", bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
  //modelAndView.addObject("storeForm", storeForm);

  //redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("errors", bindingResult.getFieldError().getRejectedValue());
        //redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("storeForm", storeForm);

    //..
    }
    //..
    }
```

**Form**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/regStoreSuccessful" commandName="storeForm">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Name store</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    <td><form:errors path="name" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><form:label path="address">Address store</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
    <td><form:errors path="address" /></td>
  </tr>
  </form:form>
```

Also I tried used `<form:errors path = "name" />`, but isn't working...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add entire object in model attribute in hasErrors method
and  for each input separately  use form:errors for each input.

```
<form:errors path = "name" />
<form:errors path = "address" />

if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    model.addAttribute("storeForm",storeForm);
//..
}
```

Comment: I edited my code (try different ways), but isn't work, I don't understand why, please look at the edited code in question above, what's problem?..

Comment: only add modelAndView.addObject("storeForm", storeForm); in your hasErrors and return the same view which you showed on get request.